# breezejs without breeze.net or oData

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, frameworks, client, breeze

I am looking for a end to end example for Breezejs library with .NET WebAPI but without using either oData or Breeze.NET (Breeze's server side component).

I have tried looking at the sample code but it doesnt seems to give an example which does that.

http://breeze.github.io/doc-samples/

All the server side samples either have oData or breeze.NET dependency.

From what I understand it is possible to use breeze.js purely in client side (and have your own server side webapi (restful)).

"**BreezeJS really is a pure JavaScript technology. You do not need any Breeze on the server. The server need not use use any Microsoft technology: not IIS, not Web API, not Entity Framework, not SQL server.**"

**Source - http://www.getbreezenow.com/spa-template**

Any help?

**Update:**

*I dont like the fact that the server is 'coupled' with the client for the metadata information. I understand this is how the breezejs functions.However and this is my personal opinion but its lot of work just to get the client side tool working with the server. This also adds traffice between server and the client. Anyway we decided to not to use breezejs because of the same overhead.  (Not saying its not good for other scenarios)*

Comment: A Breeze client asks the server to do 3 things: provide metadata, respond to queries, and handle saving changes.  The available Breeze .NET server packages are tools to help accomplish those things.  What tools would you prefer to see in a sample?  What don't you like about the provided tools?

Comment: Hi Steve, Apologies for the delay in reply. Please see the update in the question.